# Issues while apt-get update/install

Tags: 16.04, apt, kernel

I am facing issues doing this command `apt-get update` or even `install`, I am trying to update my OVH kernel version (`4.19-ovh-xxxx-std-ipv6-64`)

Here is the error

```
up linux-image-4.4.0-170-generic (4.4.0-170.199) ...
Processing triggers for linux-image-4.4.0-170-generic (4.4.0-170.199) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-170-generic
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub:
Searching for GRUB installation directory ... found: /boot/grub
/etc/default/grub: line 27: want: command not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.4.0-170-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.4.0-170-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

EDIT: Here's the grub file in /etc/default folder as some people requested them.
https://hastebin.com/onecitenog.ini

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? What is "OVH kernel version (4.19-ovh-xxxx-std-ipv6-64)"?

Comment: The pastebin mentions a 4.4 kernel; some clarification might be helpful (how does it relate to your 4.19 question? & what Pilot6 already asked)

Comment: Using ubuntu 16.0.4 | Kernel version (Linux version 4.19-ovh-xxxx-std-ipv6-64 (kernel@kernel.ovh.net) (gcc version 6.3.0 20170516 (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1))

Comment: I am not sure on how is this happening @guiverc. Although I am ready to give any debug info needed.

Comment: You now mention a **debian** kernel (4.19 is not a supported kernel for Ubuntu; it was testing only and EOL now; the package you provide is for debian old-stable (9)).

Comment: @guiverc I am sure this is an Issue with OVH, What do you suggest me to do? Do you want more debug info to insure correct kernel version?

Comment: I'm not even sure you are running Ubuntu (there is no Ubuntu 16.0.4; Ubuntu releases are *year.month* in format), and you're only precise in mentioning debian packages (debian is **not** Ubuntu).  https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic   What architecture are you on??   It could be we're assuming amd64/x86_64 when you're talking about something else - though this wouldn't clear up the debian packages!

Comment: I am very sorry @guiverc its ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Ay fixes for this please??

Comment: The log is clear, you have an error at line 27 of `/etc/default/grub`

Comment: @guiverc OP is using a kernel provided by their hosting provider (OVH), and this kernrl happens to have been built on a Debian system. This is irrelevant to the issue at hand.

Comment: @fkraiem Do you want that file to check it up? Ill send hastebin

Comment: You should edit your question to add the contents of the file.

Comment: By the way, it's unclear what you want to do. You say you want to "update my OVH kernel version", but you can't do that. Only OVH can update the OVH kernel. If you don't like this kernel and want to use another one, you must change your server settings on your OVH control panel.

Comment: I say that I want to use the default version not the OVH version, Also I’ll hastebin ghe grub file and link it here in comments when i get back to home @fkraiem or I am just going to add it the topic not an issue

Comment: @fkraiem I uploaded the file to hastebin link, I posted the link in the post above ^^